# dataset on emergency response

Tags: data-request, government

Is there any open dataset on emergency response from the government agencies? Such as 911 or fire emergency.

Ideally, the columns would be `emergency type`, `response time`, `geographic information of the caller` and `agency`.

Comment: This may also be useful? https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Social-Services/311-Service-Requests-from-2010-to-Present/erm2-nwe9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few datasets that seem to meet your requirements:

- [Paramedic Plus Response Time](https://data.acgov.org/Public-Safety/Paramedic-Plus-Response-Time/9yek-274s) from Alameda County, CA Open Data Portal (data.acgov.org)
- [PD Crime Stats Response Time](https://performance.cityofrc.us/dataset/PD-Crime-Stats-Response-Time/jptt-i8pe) (aggregated by month, not incident, but does have average dispatch time) from City of Rancho Cucamonga, CA Open Data Portal
- [Reports from Report It! SMC](https://data.smcgov.org/Environment/Reports-from-Report-It-SMC/4u6x-x6rk) are "illegal dumping issues" reported to San Mateo County, CA

Answer (score 4):

The city of Seattle publishes [real-time 911 data](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/seattle-real-time-fire-911-calls-6cdf3), since 2011 and in a variety of formats ([direct link](https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/Seattle-Real-Time-Fire-911-Calls/kzjm-xkqj))

```
Address,Type,Datetime,Latitude,Longitude,Report Location,Incident

Number 13 W Cremona St,Aid Response,06/05/2016 03:53:00 AM+0000,47.649542,-122.357807,"(47.649542, -122.357807)",F160064676
216 Union St,Aid Response,06/05/2016 07:35:00 AM+0000,47.608368,-122.337814,"(47.608368, -122.337814)",F160064776
11050 8th Av Ne,Aid Response,06/05/2016 07:43:00 AM+0000,47.708935,-122.320569,"(47.708935, -122.320569)",F160064780
```

Here's a [catalog of similar resources from Seattle](https://data.seattle.gov/browse?category=Public%20Safety)

(*[my source](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=911)*)

Comment: unfortunately, there is not a `response time` column.