# Fire incidents data

Tags: data-request, city, security, fire

I'm looking for a regularly updated list of urban fire incidents in North America or Western Europe, including:

- The date of the incident
- Address
- The type of the building: residential, business, outdoor
- Severity

Fires are the city-level issue, so cities are supposed to publish it. However, most cities publish only 311 calls, not 911 calls (except crimes).

The fire datasets I've found so far:

- **London, UK**: http://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/london-fire-brigade-incident-records. Meets all the requirements.
- **New York, US**: http://data.beta.nyc/dataset/fdny-fire-incidents. Outdated (2013).

Besides, fire departments accept FOIA requests for fire incident data (e.g. [Chicago](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/cfd.html)) and offer on-demand reports (like [San Francisco](http://sf-fire.org/fire-reports)).

Does anyone know more of the sources like these?

Comment: [This request](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/us-fire-database) concerns wildfire incidents.

Comment: @JanDoggen Well, with data it's either North America or Western Europe. So these regions would work.

Answer (score 3):

For the US, have you looked into the National Fire Incident Reporting System (NFIRS) data? That contains all of what you're looking for:

- Type of fire (indicating severity)
- Address
- Type of building
- Date of incident
- Type of structure: mixed use, industrial, office, educational, residential only, etc.

The data does not necessarily include the entire country, because not every fire department reports into NFIRS, but it does include the vast majority of it. According to USFA, "The NFIRS database comprises 75 percent of all reported fires that annually occur." You can order the data [on CD-ROM](https://www.usfa.fema.gov/data/statistics/order_download_data.html) from the U.S. Fire Administration.

You can also access the data through [Enigma Public](https://public.enigma.com/browse/77c6597b-eb82-4a2f-9d2e-5aedea1cae1d). The site currently has all NFIRS data from 2009-2013.

(Full disclosure: I work for Enigma. ;) )

Edit: Noting of course that NFIRS is not *exclusively* covering urban fires, but does encompass urban fires, including fires for NYC, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I contacted the NFIRS and they said the latest CD contains the 2014 data. I'm still looking for more recent points.

Comment: Yeah! That makes sense, they take a long time to put together the national data for each year.

Comment: @eveahe, What is Enigma?

Answer (score 2):

The city of Seattle has 911 Fire calls available on their open data platform

https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/Seattle-Real-Time-Fire-911-Calls/kzjm-xkqj

It's a live feed with data refreshed every 5 minutes, with full export and download options as well as API.

See here for more [details](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/8944/1511)

[image]