# Where to find a dataset where each record includes location?

Tags: data-request, location

I am looking for a dataset for federated learning that includes the location of each client.

For example a database for:

- **word prediction** where the location of each phone user is also included in the data records.
- **heart rate** where the location of each person is also included in the data records.
- **credit score** to predict financial distress that includes the location of each client.

any dataset that contains the location of each user and is suitable for federated learning is useful for me.

Comment: how about emergency calls (911): https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/8944/1511